# Use $scope.go() inside a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova

I have some HTML like this

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="IndexCtrl" id="indexBody">
        <h1>test</h1>
  </body>
```

Then in a javascript function like this I get the scope like this

```
function myFx() {
        var element = document.getElementById('indexBody');
        var scope = angular.element(element).scope();
        console.log(scope);
        scope.go('login');
}
```

This logs the scope in the console, but then I get an error

```
cordova.js:314 Uncaught TypeError: scope.go is not a function
```

How can I go to a new page using angular from inside this javascript function?

Thanks

Comment: _scope.go is not a function_, because `go()` is defined on `$route`

Comment: @Tushar okay is there a way I could get `$route` in the function

Comment: it's $state.go(). Not scope.go()

Comment: @BiswajitPanday you're right sorry about that I could read for a second there lol, could I get state in the function

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ui-router? If so, you can use `$state.go('destination');` in your controller, but remember to inject `$state` in the controller function.

Comment: I need to use `state.go()` inside the function `myFx` how can I do that, currently the `IndexCtrl` is empty

Comment: It's a little bit unclear for me why you are using this function to redirect to the login page. Why do you select an element by id? Do you want to redirect to the login page when this element is clicked? If this is the case, you can try something like this:

Answer (score 0):

```
You will need to use a ui-router to get to different pages.
You will need to use your Contoller file to direct your user using
click events to navigate to various pages. This is where you will use
the 'scope.go('login')'. Refer to example below.


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# authentication.config.js
# This is your ui-router and use this to go to different pages on your App
# app.foo.authentication refers to your folder stucture i.e.
# app/foo/authentication/authentication.config.js

(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.foo.authentication')
        .config(moduleConfig);

    /* @ngInject */
    function moduleConfig($translatePartialLoaderProvider, $stateProvider) {
        $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('app/foo/authentication');

        $stateProvider
        .state('authentication.login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'app/foo/authentication/login/login.tmpl.html',
            controller: 'LoginController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .state('authentication.logout', {
            url: '/logout',
            templateUrl: 'app/foo/authentication/logout/logout.tmpl.html',
            controller: 'LogoutController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        });
    }
})();

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# logout.controller.js
# This is how you will navigate from the 'Logout' page to the 'Login' page.
# app.foo.authentication refers to your folder stucture i.e.
# app/foo/authentication/logout.controller.js

(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.foo.authentication')
        .controller('LogoutController', LogoutController);

    /* @ngInject */
    function LogoutController(
        $scope,
        $state,
        $mdToast,
        $filter,
        $http,
        $window,
        triSettings,
        session) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.triSettings = triSettings;
        vm.backToLogin = backToLogin;
        vm.loading = false;

        function backToLogin () {
            vm.loading = true;
            session.end();
            $window.location.reload();
            $state.go('authentication.login');
        }
    }
})();

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# logout.tmpl.html
# This is how you will navigate from the 'Logout' page to the 'Login' page.
# app.foo.authentication refers to your folder stucture i.e.
# app/foo/authentication/logout.tmpl.html

<div layout="row" flex layout-padding layout-fill layout-align="center center">
    <div class="logout-card" flex="40" flex-lg="50" flex-md="70" flex-xs="100">
        <md-card>
            <md-toolbar class="padding-20 logout-card-header">
                <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
                    <img ng-src="{{::vm.triSettings.logo}}" alt="{{vm.triSettings.name}}">
                </div>
                <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
                    <h1 class="md-headline" translate>LOGOUT.TITLE</h1>
                </div>
            </md-toolbar>

            <md-content class="md-padding">
                <p translate>LOGOUT.MESSAGES.SUCCESS</p>

                <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
                    <md-progress-circular ng-show="vm.loading" md-mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-circular>
                </div>

                <form name="logout">
                    <md-button
                        class="md-raised md-primary full-width margin-left-0 margin-right-0 margin-top-10 margin-bottom-10"
                        ng-click="vm.backToLogin()"
                        translate="LOGOUT.MESSAGES.LOGIN_NOW"
                        aria-label="{{'LOGOUT.MESSAGES.LOGIN_NOW' | translate}}">
                    </md-button>
                </form>
            </md-content>
        </md-card>
    </div>
</div>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```